# Magento 2 web API authentication

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

I am trying to login a user throw API and after that use token on frontend in browser. Some tests passed, some not. Does anybody did something like this: Login user throw web API "/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token" or something similar to get a token which could be used as cookie PHPSESID? in order to continue as web user.

Than you in advance.